# ASP.NET API service working with multiple databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web-services, api

I'm building a web .net API and basically i have Controller and Service which needs SQL query (big one) and a database to take the information. I have a lot of SQL`s and 4 databases. So the service do exactly the same thing no matter the base, but how is the best way do switch between these databases?

The SQL's have their own DB, only for them, in which apart from their names, `fileNames` and etc. it can be seen on which Database they should be used.

I'm using Entity Framework Code First Approach and I`m looking for options how to do it.

1. Since the service always do exactly the same, maybe create 4 contexts for each base, and pass the correct one to the service in the controller (probably with IF`s, which doesn't sound good to me)
2. Or maybe create 4 controllers depending on the Database and Context and every controller passes the correct Context... doesn't seems very logical either.

That is why I need your help :)

So the overview:
asp.net API, Controller and a Service doing always the same but for four different databases(receiving SQL query file, read the query from the DB and send the info to Front-end as Json).Also the queries have their own DB (for now).

Comment: How do you decide which database you need to use? It would make sense to add some kind of switch statement there so you use the correct DbContext instance.

Comment: Every SQL query contains info on which DB must be run, that is one of the reasons to have DB only for the SQl`s, so when i search the DB for specific SQL requeired by the Front-End, I have I check the DB that is required and then I know which DB i need. So depending on the SQL query. One query is for Base A other for Base B and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same questions as hbulens, I'm not sure how you are deciding which database to use.  In the absence of that information, I'll assume you know somehow. Assuming the different Contexts have the same DbSets I would look to override `OnConfiguring` in your DB Context and create the connection string there, something like this

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var connectionString = $"<Your new connection string with {variables}>";
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

That way you can continue to inject the DbContext as normal and your consumer (Controllers/Service) will get the one specific context they need rather than getting all the possible Contexts.